# Embed form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to embed a form in a page.js React component. The script `src` is loaded on the page, but not the form code.

Here is the original HTML embed code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://koi-3QNK98WC9Y.marketingautomation.services/client/form.js?ver=2.0.1"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ss_form = {'account': 'MzawMDE3tzQzBQA', 'formID': 'M0xNNjW2TDXSTUozMNI1MU421U00Sk7UTU5OTbJIs0wyTrVMBAA'};
              ss_form.width = '100%';
              ss_form.domain = 'app-3QNK98WC9Y.marketingautomation.services';
              ss_form.target_id = 'form'; 
              ss_form.polling = true; 
</script>
```

Here is what I currently have in React:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

 function Contact() {
   
  useEffect(() => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src='https://koi-3QNK98WC9Y.marketingautomation.services/client/form.js?ver=2.0.1';
      document.body.appendChild(script);

      script.addEventListener('load', () => {         
          var ss_form = {'account': 'MzawMDE3tzQzBQA', 'formID': 'M0xNNjW2TDXSTUozMNI1MU421U00Sk7UTU5OTbJIs0wyTrVMBAA'};
          ss_form.width = '100%';
          ss_form.domain = 'app-3QNK98WC9Y.marketingautomation.services';
          ss_form.target_id = 'form'; 
          ss_form.polling = true; 
      });
      
  }, []);
    
    return (
    <main>
      <div id="form"> </div>
    </main>
    );

  }

export default Contact;
```

Where the form was supposed to appear (inside de #form div) it's just blank and no code is rendered.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have to listen for the load event, and use an element reference (useRef). [This is an example for loading a google map](https://publiuslogic.com/blog/google-maps+react-hooks/) but the principles are the same.

Comment: The `ss_form.target_id = 'form'` is set to render the form inside the #form div already, no need for a <Form /> reference. I just need to make the script load inside the <head> element as it is.

Comment: I tried to use Helmet for this but the form appears sometimes, others it won't. Since I can't resolve the issue as why the script sometimes won't load the form using Helmet I'm trying to implement it with useEffect() instead.